# Write a test class without DML statements

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I write a test method for the following class?

```
public Class checkRecursive
{
  private static boolean run = true;
  public boolean runOnce() {
    if (run)
    {
      run = false;
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return run;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying like this

```
@isTest

public class recursiveTests {

  public static testMethod void testrecursive() {
    test.starttest();
    checkrecursive cr = new checkrecursive();
    cr.runOnce();
    test.stoptest();
  }
}
```

But it covers nothing. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that checkRecursive will not run as expected during unit tests; the static variable doesn't reset during test execution over multiple trigger contexts in the same test method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time `runOnce()` is called it is expected to return `true`, any further calls will return `false`. So we just need to write the test to assert that this is the case.

```
@isTest
public class RecursiveTests {

    @isTest
    static void testRecursive() {
        CheckRecursive cr = new CheckRecursive();

        System.assertEquals(true, cr.runOnce());

        System.assertEquals(false, cr.runOnce());
        System.assertEquals(false, cr.runOnce());
        System.assertEquals(false, cr.runOnce());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually copied your code exactly in my dev org and ran tests and I am getting 83% coverage.  Are you sure you are looking at the coverage of the class itself and nit the test class?

[image]

Comment: It shown as none